# How to disable Taskbar Thumbnail preview in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, taskbar, windows-10, thumbnails, preview

Just wanted to disable window preview thumbnail in the taskbar:

[image]

This is just the same as [How to disable Taskbar Thumbnail preview in Windows 8 ?](https://superuser.com/questions/755553/how-to-disable-taskbar-thumbnail-preview-in-windows-8) .

I followed some solutions written in the answer, but none of them seem to work or dont exist registry codes in Windows 10

Any suggestion for this? Better if its not needed to install a program like Taskbar Tweaker

Comment: laktak's answer in the linked question (changing or creating a DWORD value called `ExtendedUIHoverTime` in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced` with the value `41fffffe`) worked for me on Windows 10. You just have to restart your computer after the changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just after writing this question I found an executable file that seems to tweak thumbnails without installing any program. It can be found here: http://winaero.com/download.php?view.27

Just open it and click `Disable thumbnails`, then `Apply`

[image]

Done.

Comment: Interesting. If it doesn't have to install anything or run all the time, surely it's just modifying the Registry somewhere; anyone know which keys?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to download a program to do this.  You can search for `NumThumbnails` Registry on the Internet and find several answers, some have a program.  But the best just refer you to updating the registry.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Taskband
```

Change Taskbar Thumbnail Threshold by setting `NumThumbnails` to `0`.

If you don't have a `NumThumbnails` DWORD, then you'll need to create one.

Remember - updating the registry can be dangerous if you do not know what you are doing. For complete instructions you can see this page here: [Answers.Microsoft - How do I change Taskbar icon preview](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-do-i-change-taskbar-icon-preview-from/fed816fe-9120-4613-b6f8-ca85bd9a614e)